# Multidimensional array to string php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have below array and i am trying to convert to string separated with comma.

```
$users_array = Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [user_id] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [user_id] => 5
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [user_id] => 6
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [user_id] => 13
            )

    )

)
```

Then i tried to convert in string with foreach

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($users_array); $i++){
    $xyz[] = implode(",",$users_array[$i]);
}
$users = implode(',',$xyz);
```

But it throw error `Message:  Array to string conversion`

How can i convert it to string like `1,5,6,13`?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($users_array); $i++){
   for($j = 0; $j < count($users_array[$i]; $j++)) {
       $xyz[] = $users_array[$i][$j]["user_id"];
    }
}
$users = implode(',',$xyz);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$user_ids = array();
foreach($users_array as $val){
    foreach($val as $v)){
       array_push($user_ids,$v['user_id']);
    }
} 
$users = implode(',',$user_ids);
```

This code is very easy and also use for as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

> hey @rjcode in php if you want to convert an array to comma separated
>   string so use function implode(separation letter, $array) and for vice
>   versa means string to an array so use function explode(separation
>   letter, string)

for your case use use implode() so for your code try below one

```
 <?php
    for($i = 0; $i < count($users_array); $i++){
   for($j = 0; $j < count($users_array[$i]; $j++)) {
       $xyz[] = $users_array[$i][$j]["user_id"];
    }
    }
    $users = implode(',',$xyz);
?>
```